# Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutralin JetBrains dotCover

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, dotcover

I am working on code coverage analysis on.net core and i am using  JetBrains dotCover, while executing on runtime i am getting file not found exception. could you please help me on this

TIA

Comment: Please add your code in question.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyzeParams>
  <TargetExecutable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>\testcontainer:path.tests.dll</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>path</TargetWorkingDir>
  <TempDir>c:\Temp</TempDir>
  <Output>output.html</Output>
  <ReportType>HTML</ReportType>
 
 </AnalyzeParams>

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting same error through command line.[image]

Team City 10.0.5 bundled with dotCover 2016.2.2, but i need to use latest version of dot cover 2017.2.2. I extracted dotcover CLI tools and try to run from the command line as mentioned here.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html